# My iframe won't keep its src value after it has been changed with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am new to working with iframes, and HTML/JavaScript in general. I am trying to change the iframe `src` when the user clicks on the `submit` button. However, for some reason the `src` value keeps reverting to the original value after I change it. Please ignore the unusual id names. :)

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Card Getter</title>
<script>
  function get(){
    var name = document.getElementById("card").value;
    document.getElementById("toast").src="http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&name=+["+name+"]";
    alert(name);
  };
  function check(){
    alert(document.getElementById("toast").src);
  };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="" id="toast"></iframe>
  <form>
    <p>Card Name:</p>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="card">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="get()" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <form>
    <input type="button" onclick="check()" value="check">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your DOM.

Comment: @Nit I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your form is submitted when the button is pressed. Since you didn’t specific a form action, the current page is assumed—so this results in a reload which resets the iframe’s `src`.

As a quick fix, you can add `return false;` to your `onclick` handler:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="get(); return false;" value="Submit">
```

This will prevent the form from being submitted.

Comment: @Zaros Glad to hear. Would be great if you could also accept my answer :)